# Why there is difference in Active scan report for same application in ZAP TOOL

Tags: security, testing, zap

I am using ZAP TOOL for security testing and
Doing two active scans for the same application without changing anything, the results are different.
For example, in the first scan for the same url it shows me a possible SQL injection in some parameters and when I launch it a second time for the same url it shows me the possible injection in other parameters. I don't know if the data used to make the request can also influence, or the data in the database

If haven't changed on application, I have done manual scan using Active scan and every time i got different result for same application . Can anyone have any idea why is happening ?

Is the Zaps tools uses the different scripts/attack files every time for Active scan.
I would like to know what factors influence different results and where can I find out how active scanning actually works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the ZAP configuration *and the environment* are exactly the same each time then ZAP will make the same requests. The 'environment' is the problem as there are so many variables, including your app state, db state, the processing loads on the machines ZAP and the target are running on, the load on the network etc etc.

Some of the SQL injection attacks are timing based and so these can be affected by all of the above factors.

If ZAP reports a problem like SQL injection then I'd strongly recommend investigating it further, even if it is only shown sporadically.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I further want to ask After fixing the SQL injection issues we ran the same test on same environment and its showing "Cross Site Scripting (Reflected)
" as high alert. This same error was fixed when we tested the application on ZAP. Can you tell how Cross Site Scripting attacks works in ZAP tool as you have explained SQL injection ?

Comment: The help already described this rule fairly well at a high level :) https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/desktop/addons/active-scan-rules/#cross-site-scripting-reflected